# Unable to implement pause functionality in cocos2dx

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have a class that handles and plays the entire game. I tried to implement the pause and restart functionality.However, cannot find the right tutorial.
I want to implement a functionality to pause the game when the pauseButton is pressed. But I'm not sure where and how. How is a pause and restart or returning one scene back handled in cocos2dx? I would love to hear from you!

Part of my code. How to add a pause in the pauseButton ?

```
  Scene* GameLayer::createScene(int level)
    {
        auto scene = Scene::create();
        auto layer = GameLayer::create(level);
        scene->addChild(layer);
        return scene;
    }

    GameLayer* GameLayer::create(int level)
    {
        GameLayer *pRet = new GameLayer();
        pRet->init(level);
        pRet->autorelease();

        return pRet;
    }

    bool GameLayer::init(int level)
    {
        if (!Layer::init())
            return false;

        auto touchListener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
        touchListener->setSwallowTouches(_swallowsTouches);
        touchListener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(GameLayer::onTouchBegan, this);
        touchListener->onTouchMoved = CC_CALLBACK_2(GameLayer::onTouchMoved, this);
        touchListener->onTouchEnded = CC_CALLBACK_2(GameLayer::onTouchEnded, this);
        touchListener->onTouchCancelled = CC_CALLBACK_2(GameLayer::onTouchCancelled, this);
        _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(touchListener, this);

            auto pauseButton = MenuItemImage::create("pause1.png","pause2.png",[](Ref*sender){
    //Do pause and show the pause menu

            });
              auto menu = Menu::create(pauseButton, NULL);
              menu->setPosition(WINSIZE.width / 2.0, WINSIZE.height - 50);
              addChild(menu, ZOrder::Level);
        initBackground(); 
        initBalls(); 
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `Layer` or may be `ColorLayer` with some opacity and add to your current `Scene/Layer`. Add pause Dialog content like Pause Label, Resume Button on that layer and remove that layer when you resume.

```
auto pauseButton = MenuItemImage::create("pauseNormal.png","pauseSelected.png",[](Ref*sender){

        if(!Director::getInstance()->isPaused())
            Director::getInstance()->pause();
        else
            Director::getInstance()->resume();
    });

auto buttons = Menu::create(pauseButton,NULL);
addChild(buttons);
buttons->setPosition(visibleSize.width / 2.0, visibleSize.height / 2.0);
```

**EDIT**

```
auto pauseLayer=LayerColor::create(Color4B::BLACK, visibleSize.width,visibleSize.height);

auto pauseLabel=Label::createWithTTF("Paused", "fonts/Marker Felt.ttf", 24);
pauseLabel->setPosition(origin.x+visibleSize.width/2,origin.y+visibleSize.height-50);
pauseLayer->addChild(pauseLabel);

// Add your required content to pauseLayer like pauseLabel
pauseLayer->setVisible(false);
pauseLayer->setOpacity(220);  // so that gameplay is slightly visible
addChild(pauseLayer);

auto pauseButton = MenuItemImage::create("pauseNormal.png","pauseSelected.png",[pauseLayer](Ref*sender){

    if(!Director::getInstance()->isPaused()){
       Director::getInstance()->pause();
       pauseLayer->setVisible(true);
    }
    else {
        Director::getInstance()->resume();
        pauseLayer->setVisible(false);
    }

});

auto buttons = Menu::create(pauseButton,NULL);
addChild(buttons);
buttons->setPosition(visibleSize.width / 2.0, visibleSize.height / 2.0);
```

Comment: Thank you , do you know a link or a sample to connect a Layer and a Directors isPaused?

Comment: I don't know such link but you can easily created your own Layer and can simulate with Pause/Resume buttons.

Comment: When I added a ColorLayer inside the if condition for the if paused I got the following error. "error: 'this' was not captured for this lambda function".  The error is pointing to the addChild(colorLayer); that I've added.

Comment: `by reference [&]` you need to use reference in capturelist of lambda function, after that you can able to add child inside lambda function, each time creation of new object(pauseLayer) and deletion is not good solution so I use `setVisible` method on my my pauseLayer, check updated Answer

Comment: Thank you, perfect solution!